# TreeView in wpf ... Is there a SelectedItemChanging event?

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I am making use of a System.Windows.Controls.TreeView in a wpf application.

Basically I need the equivalent of a SelectedItemChanging event so that I can cancel the the selection event of the treeview.

Is there a way to do this? I was not able to find something called SelectedItemschanging event on a treeview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on how to do [treeview item selection by code](http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/programmatically-selecting-an-item-in-a-treeview/).

You could use the techniques from that article in conjunction with the NewValue and OldValue members of the RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs in SelectedItemChanged.